# JPA multiple count

Tags: sql, jpa

I have a table A with the columns x, y and z. I want to make a query to count the rows where (A.x=1 and A.y=4), (A.x=2 and A.y=7) and (A.x=3 and A.y=3). The result should consist of 3 integers, corresponding to the above criterias.

I don't know if this kind of query is possible.

I would like a sample code in JPA Criteria(preferably) or JPQL or, in worst case, SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your worst case scenario:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.x = 1 AND a.y = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Result1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.x = 2 AND a.y = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Result2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.x = 3 AND a.y = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Result3
FROM TableA a
```

Comment: OK, so it IS possible in SQL, that means it should be possible in JPQL also. That is why, I should expect a Criteria translator. :D Thank you, at least I know I can do it somehow.